# itunes connectでリジェクト

Tags: ios, iphone

iTunes connectでアプリのバージョンアップを行ったのですが、以下のメッセージでリジェクトされました。何を修正したらよろしいのでしょうか。

> Before you Submit
>
> Your app does not comply with the Guidelines for Using Apple's
>   Trademarks and Copyrights. Specifically, your app includes:
>
> The term iOS in the device name.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app and its metadata to address these trademark
>   issues.
>
> For your convenience, we've provided the relevant section/s of the
>   Guidelines for Using Apple's Trademarks and Copyrights:
>
> Product Names Guidelines
>
> You may use Apple, iPhone, or any other Apple word mark (but not the
>   Apple Logo or other Apple-owned graphic symbol/logo) in a referential
>   phrase on packaging or promotional/advertising materials to describe
>   that the third party product is compatible with the referenced Apple
>   product or technology, provided they comply with the following
>   requirements:
>
> - The Apple word mark is not part of the product name.
> - The Apple word mark is used in a referential phrase such as "runs on", "for use with", "for", or "compatible with".
> - The Apple word mark appears less prominent than the product name.
> - The product is in fact compatible with, or otherwise works with, the referenced Apple product.
> - The reference to Apple does not create a sense of endorsement, sponsorship, or false association with Apple or Apple products or
>     services.
> - The use does not show Apple or its products in a false or derogatory light.
>
> In other words, whether appearing on the application itself and/or in
>   marketing materials, the word iPhone may be used as a descriptor, but
>   not as part of the product name.

<< 追記 >>
説明のスクリーンショットでこのようなiPhone端末が見えるものを使用しています。よくApp storeなどで見かけるのですがこれが原因の可能性があるということでしょうか。
[image: このような画像です]

Comment: この情報だけでは判断がつきませんが、リジェクトの理由としてはAppleの製品に関する情報を説明やアイコン、スクリーンショット、アプリ内などに使われているのではないでしょうか？(iPhoneの外装の画像や、Appleのロゴなど画像に関するものや、文言の中に”Apple"など禁止ワードが含まれている可能性)

Answer (score 3):

まずは、レビュワーからの連絡にはっきりと書かれている事柄を調べてみるべきでしょう。

> Specifically, your app includes:
>
> The term iOS in the device name.
>   (具体的には、あなたのアプリには「iOSという語がdevice nameに」存在します。)

と言われているのですから、あなたのアプリ(一部に metadata なんて書いてあって、勘違いしそうになるのですが、普通にバージョンアップ版アプリをレビューに提出されたのだとしたら、審査の対象はメタデータだけではなく、アプリそのものも含みます)に「iOS」と言う単語が使われていないか調べるべきでしょう。(device nameと言う項目はiTunes Connectのアプリのメタデータ画面にはなかったはずなので、アプリそのものという可能性が高いと思うのですが。ただし、レビュワーからのリジェクト連絡はどこが悪いのかわかりにくいことは多いようです。)

上に書いたように、調べるべき対象はアプリ名／アプリの説明／画面イメージなどのメタデータの他、アプリそのものの各画面も含まないといけません。(例えば審査用のテストデータなどに「iOS」と書かれているだけでアウトになる可能性があります。もちろん操作イメージ中でも。)

(1) 調べても"iOS"なんて単語は見つからなかった場合

Appleにその旨申告して、どの画面のどの部分のことを言っているのか教えてもらう

(2) 簡単に削除/修正できる場所に"iOS"と言う単語を使っているのが見つかった

その部分を削除/修正したバージョンをビルドして、再度審査に提出する。

- リジェクトによる再提出であること
- リジェクトされた理由
- その部分は確かに修正したことと確認すべき箇所

なんかを明記した方が、迅速に審査を進めてもらえるでしょう。

(3) "iOS"と言う単語は使っているが、Appleのルール的にOKのはずだ

"iOS"と言う単語が使われている場所とその意図を明確にした上で、それはこのルールに従って認められているはずだと言うことを主張しましょう。英語力がないと少々辛いかもしれません。

ちなみにこの場合、「Appleのルール的にOKのはず」ではなく、「App Storeで既に公開されているアプリにも同じようなのがあるじゃないか」なんて言い方をしてもほとんど取り合ってもらえません。AppleのDevForumに時々書き込みがありますが、「私たちは、あなたのアプリをAppleの定めたルールに従って審査している(から、他のアプリのことなんて知らないよ!)」と言ったテンプレの返信が来るだけ、ということが多いようです。

---

「iOSという語」が何を表しているのかしっかり調べて、その結果に応じてきちんとAppleに連絡を取ってください。他の回答に書かれていますが、このサイトの回答者が何百人OKだNGだと騒いでも、Appleのレビュワーがどんな判定を下すかはわかりません。

Answer (score 0):

これらの問題については当事者とAppleの審査担当の方しかわかりません。
※技術的なリジェクトではなく、内容のリジェクトです。

問題解決センターに何が問題なのか、問い合わせるのが一番です。
また、原因に心当たりになるものに関してリストアップし、伝えてください。
Appleはそれなりに親切なので、対応してくれると思います。

Answer (score 0):

画像のようなApple製品の画像は利用するための規約があります。
この場合、iPhoneの全体像が見えてはいけません。
例えばホームボタンを隠す。もしくはホームボタンを削るなどしないといけません。
Apple製品の全体画像は利用規約に縛られます。

リジェクト内容はリジェクトの理由の番号があるので
検索するとリジェクト内容共有している方もいるので引っかかると思います。
質問内容には一番重要なリジェクト理由の部分が無いので分かりません。
(※リジェクトのタイトルなどに書いています。)

アプリの詳細が分からないとメタデータのリジェクトなどはアドバイスしづらいので、
Appleへ問い合わせしてみるのもいいかと思います。

ただ、問い合わせフォーム(メール対応)は英語のみの対応なので
英語に自信がない場合は電話で直接尋ねるのも有りです
[電話番号の一覧](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/jp/)はこちらにあるので電話してみるのもありです。

参考：[Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Copyrights](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html)

---

Appleでリジェクトされる場合、リジェクト理由をコピペしたような内容なので、
色々な理由のドレが原因か、レビューチームに尋ねるかご自身で想定して切り分ける必要があります。
質問文のコメントにも記載しておりますが、画像・名称の使用も審査対象です。
[新しいガイドライン](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)では番号分けされていませんが"旧8.1"の項目ですね。
商標権に関する項目になります。

Comment: iOS開発には詳しくないので質問の英文を読んだだけですが、"Specifically, your app includes: The term iOS in the device name." という箇所は関係ないのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 追記しましたが、関係ございます。質問文の追記で画像を追加されて尋ねていらっしゃったので画像について言及しました。他にも”Android"という名称など、使用に商標権が絡む文言がこのリジェクト内容に関係してきますね。